# C Scope Question (Call by Value): Why don't I have to declare globally in this mergesort implementation?

Tags: arrays, c, scope, pass-by-reference, mergesort

I have a basic question regarding scope in C: why does the following code from geeksforgeeks work? My info is: variable calls are call by value, i.e. anything that happens to say, the array arr inside a function does not translate to the outside.

```
/* C program for Merge Sort */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
// Merges two subarrays of arr[].
// First subarray is arr[l..m]
// Second subarray is arr[m+1..r]
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;
 
    /* create temp arrays */
    int L[n1], R[n2];
 
    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
 
    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
 
    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there
    are any */
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
 
    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there
    are any */
    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
 
/* l is for left index and r is right index of the
sub-array of arr to be sorted */
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r) {
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
        // large l and h
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
 
        // Sort first and second halves
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);
 
        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}
 
/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int A[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
 
/* Driver code */
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7 };
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
 
    printf("Given array is \n");
    printArray(arr, arr_size);
 
    mergeSort(arr, 0, arr_size - 1);
 
    printf("\nSorted array is \n");
    printArray(arr, arr_size);
    return 0;
}
```

To be more concrete: why don't I have to declare arr globally for this to work? How come the last print call gives me the correct array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an array is used in expressions it is with rare exception implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

On the other hand, the compiler adjusts a function parameter having an array type to pointer to the array element type. That is this function declaration

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r);
```

is equivalent to

```
void merge(int *arr, int l, int m, int r);
```

Thus all elements of the passed array are passed by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it.

So using the pointer arithmetic and a pointer to the first element of an array you can access and change all original elements of the passed array.

Pay attention to that the subscript operator as for example `arr[i]` is calculated like `*( arr + i )`.

Pay attention to that using a global array when functions depend on the global array is a bad practice. In such a case the functions can not be called with different array of different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are *not* passed by value. In C, arrays are not first class objects, e.g. you can't assign to arrays, only to elements of an array. You can't return arrays from functions.

Instead, a **pointer to the first element** is passed by value. This allows the called function to modify elements of the array. This automatic rewrite of an array expression is sometimes described as *an array decays to a pointer to its first element*.

Any decent book on C should have a section explaining this special behavior of arrays in expressions.

The corresponding reference from the ISO C99 Standard is in **6.3.2.1#3 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**:

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a
> string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
> converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of
> the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the
> behavior is undefined

Answer (score 1):

As an argument, the declaration `int arr[]` is really exactly the same as `int *arr`. You *don't* copy the array itself when calling the function.

The "value" that is passed is the pointer value itself (where the pointer is pointing).